# Getting a collection of values from a JSON ByteString using lens-aeson

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

Say I have a JSON ByteString that looks something like

```
{
    messages: [
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

I'd like to use lens to get a list/vector of messages out of it. I have a function `toMessage` that can turn a `Value` into a `Maybe Message`.

I've tried this composition `key "messages" . values . to toMessage` (`to` is from `Control.Lens.Getter` but the result is `Maybe Message` and it simply becomes `Nothing`.

Currently I'm doing this

```
msgsJson <- c ^? key "messages"
let msgs = toList $ mapMaybe message $ msgsJson ^.. values
```

(`mapMaybe` is from `witherable`, `toList` is to convert the `Vector` into a list)
but I'd like to know if there's a way to compose various lenses to get a single lens that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, this works for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens

newtype Message =
  Message Integer
  deriving (Show)

toMessage :: Value -> Maybe Message
toMessage json_ = do
  i <- json_ ^? key "a" . _Integer
  return (Message i)

input :: ByteString
input = "{\"messages\":[{\"a\":1},{\"a\":2},{\"a\":3}]}"

main :: IO ()
main =
  print (input ^.. (key "messages" . values . to toMessage))
```

```
λ> main
[Just (Message 1),Just (Message 2),Just (Message 3)]
```

If you're getting `Nothing`, it could mean that your JSON is invalid (you can test it with `decode json :: Maybe Value`). Or that any other optic in the composition is failing. With long dotted optics it's sometimes hard to tell exactly which one is failing except by lopping parts off the end and retrying. But your composed optic `key "messages" . values . to toMessage` should Just Work™.

By the way:

```
msgJson <- c ^? key "messages"
let msgs = toList $ mapMaybe message $ msgsJson ^.. values
```

should be the same as

```
msgJson <- c ^? key "messages"
let msgs = toList $ msgsJson ^.. (values . to message . _Just)
```

and

```
msgJson <- c ^? key "messages"
let msgs = msgsJson ^.. (values . to message . _Just)
```

and

```
let msgs = c ^.. (key "messages" . values . to message . _Just)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to give it a try again. See what I did wrong the first time.